# Spark SFTP library can not download the file from sftp server when running in EMR

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sftp

I am using com.springml.spark.sftp in my spark job to download the file from sftp server. The basic code is as following.

```
      val sftpDF = spark.read.
            schema(my_schema).
            format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
            option("host", "myhost.test.com").
            option("username", "myusername").
            option("password", "mypassword").
            option("inferSchema", "false").
            option("fileType", "csv").
            option("delimiter", ",").
            option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").
            load("/data/test.csv.gz")
```

It runs well when I run it in my local machine by using "spark-submit spark.jar". However, when I tried to run it in EMR, it shew the following errors. It seems it spark job tried to find the file in HDFS instead of SFTP.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: hdfs://ip-10-61-82-166.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/test.csv.gz;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:558)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
        at com.springml.spark.sftp.DatasetRelation.read(DatasetRelation.scala:44)
        at com.springml.spark.sftp.DatasetRelation.<init>(DatasetRelation.scala:29)
        at com.springml.spark.sftp.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
        at com.example.App$.main(App.scala:134)
        at com.example.App.main(App.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:853)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:937)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

What could be wrong? Do I need register some DataSource for SFTP module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the reason. The version of 1.1.0 of this sftp library was used. It downloads the file to the folder of driver instead of executor. It is the reason that the error was generated when I ran it in the cluster mode instead of standalone mode. I also noticed the same issue asked here. https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp/issues/24. After upgrading the version of sftp library from 1.1.0 to 1.1.3, the problem was solved.

Comment: I am currently using 1.1.3 version of spark sftp yet, I am getting the same error while running on cluster mode. Can you please tell if you did anything else apart from changing the version?